# How to sync `yarn.lock` with `package.json`?

Tags: node.js, package.json, yarnpkg

I installed a package with `yarn add --dev`, run its setup process and during it, the package installed several other packages and added those to `package.json` (in `devDependencies`), I assume with **npm**. Great, but now my `yarn.lock` is out of sync.

What is the correct, non-manual way of syncing `yarn.lock` to the current state of `package.json`?

Edit: `yarn check` shows the missing packages as:

```
error Lockfile does not contain pattern: <package>@<version>
```

But it doesn't add them.

Comment: What was the module you installed that made changes to your `package.json`? Seems like pretty bad form to me.

Comment: @sdgluck the package was `eslint`, and the setup process `eslint --init`

Comment: @sdgluck would you repost your answer? I don't know why you (or someone else) deleted it. `yarn install` did indeed work (not the most intuitive workflow me thinks)

Comment: hey, consider using the tool I made in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46904544/sync-yarn-lock-back-into-package-json-and-lock/46917907#46917907   works like a charm!

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Run `yarn install`, or just `yarn`.

The lock file is updated in its entirety on any change to dependencies, i.e. when you run a yarn command.

From the [Yarn docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/yarn-lock/#toc-managed-by-yarn):

> Your yarn.lock file is auto-generated and should be handled entirely by Yarn. **As you add/upgrade/remove dependencies with the Yarn CLI, it will automatically update your yarn.lock file.** Do not edit this file directly as it is easy to break something.

*(Emphasis my own)*

Comment: What is the purpose of deleting it first? What kind of issues might I run into if not?

Comment: There was no need to delete the file.

Comment: @MauricioPasquierJuan I had to delete mine

Comment: I don't know if this was correct, but I could solve my problem only by deleting the `yarn.lock`: `react-intl` defined `"@types/react": "16 || 17 || 18"`. The latest version of `@types/react` was `18.2.12`, which I used for my package.json, but yarn installed only `18.0.28` for `react-intl`, which caused type errors _(The type `FunctionComponent` was changed in v18.2 in [commit 443451ccc5db3adf1865853e152636f1a9ba5dd5](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/443451ccc5db3adf1865853e152636f1a9ba5dd5#diff-32cfd8cb197872bcba371f5018185d2e75fa540b52cda2dd7d8ac12dcc021299R553))_.

Answer (score -1):

If you ever face a checksum issue this will solve it,

```
YARN_CHECKSUM_BEHAVIOR=update yarn
```

Answer (score -1):

**Generates a lock file entry.**

```
yarn generate-lock-entry
```

Note: This command is considered for advanced use-cases and tooling only. It generates a lock file entry given the current package.json manifest file.