# sync yarn.lock back into package.json and lock

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, yarnpkg

I have `package.json` and `yarn.lock` files.
yarn.lock has versions locked in, I would like to sync, and lock (without the `^`) all the versions in yarn.lock, back into package.json.

Is there any easy way to do that?

In the end, I would like to not have `"^"` in my package.json at all as it leads to too many troubles, and I would like to upgrade packages specifically and not unknowingly when I run a fresh yarn install.

Is there any tool or way to quickly replace the versions in package.json with those exsisting inside yarn.lock?

Comment: How is this not supported by `yarn upgrade-interactive` already?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I ended up making something myself:

[sync-yarnlock-into-packagejson](https://github.com/vasilevich/sync-yarnlock-into-packagejson)

its a tiny utility that can sync existing package.json with yarn.lock.

## syncyarnlock

Syncs `yarn.lock` versions into an exsisting `package.json` file, removing dynamic numbers such as with ^, keeping static versions intact.

### Install

##### YARN

`yarn global add syncyarnlock`

#### or

##### NPM

`npm install -g syncyarnlock`

### Usage

```
  Usage: syncyarnlock [options]

  Sync `yarn.lock` package versions, into package.json
  Options:

    -V, --version                output the version number
    -d, --dir <path>             directory path where the yarn.lock file is located (default to current directory)
    -p, --dirPackageJson <path>  directory of project with target package.json, if not set, -d will be used
    -s, --save                   By default don't override the package.json file, make a new one instead package.json.yarn
    -k, --keepUpArrow            By default the ^ or any other dynamic numbers are removed and replaced with static ones.
    -g, --keepGit                By default direct git repositories are also replaced by the version written in yarn.
    -l, --keepLink               By default direct link: repositories are also replaced by the version written in yarn.
    -a, --keepVariable <variable>By default everything is converted to yarn version, write a part of the type you wish not to convert, seperate by comma if more than one, to not replace git and link you would use +,link:
    -h, --help                   output usage information
  Transforms yarn.lock files to JSON
  
  Examples:
  //perform inside a directory with yarn.lock and package.json, will output package.json.yarn in the same directory.
  syncyarnlock
```

Comment: Can you check the issue mentioned at this link -  https://github.com/vasilevich/sync-yarnlock-into-packagejson/issues/1

Comment: yes I did, thanks for letting me know, I will fix it as soon as I can