# Sails.js 1.1.0 Security issue: Upgrade lodash to version 4.17.13 or later

Tags: sails.js, lodash

I created a new project using [Sails.js](https://sailsjs.com/) and when I pushed it to github I am getting a security alert:
Upgrade lodash to version 4.17.13 or later
Problem is I can't seem to upgrade the lodash version. Sails is using `"@sailshq/lodash": "^3.10.3"` I tried `yarn install lodash@4.17.13` but the yarn.lock still have the old version.

Anybody knows how to upgrade the lodash version?

Here is the full alert:
**CVE-2019-10744**
**high severity**

Vulnerable versions: < 4.17.13
Patched version: 4.17.13
Affected versions of lodash are vulnerable to Prototype Pollution.
The function defaultsDeep could be tricked into adding or modifying properties of Object.prototype using a constructor payload.

Comment: `sailsjs` maintains their own fork of lodash, so you better contact them.

Comment: Edit the file package.json. Then run `yarn`. See [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41126217/how-to-sync-yarn-lock-with-package-json#41126235)

Comment: sails.js locked their lodash version @zerkms this is why I am asking it here...

Comment: I edited the package.json and run yarn @AllanLindJensen but the yarn lock resolved to an older version.

Comment: "this is why I am asking it here" --- why? sailsjs is who picks what version is to be used. As long as you don't want to maintain your own fork of sailsjs (don't you?) - you cannot do anything but ask them to address the problem.