# Why does yarn keeps trying to load packages I uninstalled?

Tags: yarnpkg, postcss

I uninstalled a package named "post-uncss" and even though it's not on my packages.json it's still trying to load it. I used yarn remove post-uncss then even ran just yarn and still
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlqd7.png)

this is for a website i am building using Sage Theme starter

Comment: This sounds like it might have something to do with that package still being referenced by your `yarn.lock` file. Odd though, since `yarn remove <package>` should've fixed this.

Comment: is there a way to update yarn.lock after uninstalling a package?

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41126235/11047824) it looks like you should just run `yarn` or `yarn install` (functionally the same). If that doesn't work, you can try deleting (or moving for safe keeping) `yarn.lock` and then running the same command, which will generate a brand new lock file based on your `package.json`.